# REQUEST_TIME is in GMT eventhough site timezone is IST

Tags: 7, datetime

In admin/config/regional/settings I can see that IST timezone is set.

But when I print REQUEST_TIME constant I see GMT one.

How to get the IST time in REQUEST_TIME ?

Comment: I assume you refer to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

> The entries in this array are created by the web server.

Drupal has no control over this, and in fact, neither does PHP. (Though of course both of them are free to manipulate the value)

Comment: Thanks I've changed the php.ini as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596083/apache-time-stamp-incorrect/8596163#8596163